# certificate fails for staging.mydomain.com

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've cloned a copy of a live site to a new staging server, staging.mydomain.com, but I'm getting a certificate error on the new server:
`server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

Are certificates valid for subdomains?

Additionally will the certificate work without changes to any of the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are certificates valid for subdomains?

This depends on the certificate. A wildcard certificate with a subject alternative names of `*.example.com` is valid for `subdomain.example.com` but not for `subsubdomain.subdomain.example.com`. A certificate with subject alternative names only for `example.com` and `www.example.com` is neither valid for `subdomain.example.com` nor `subsubdomain.www.example.com`.

Comment: Thank you, we have a wildcard certificate, which is managed by another organisation, do they need to add the IP address or do I need to change any of the certificate files or something as we are getting the invalid cert error?

Comment: @jp1977: The client checks the hostname in the URL against the subject alternative names in the certificate. If it matches, there is nothing additionally to do, i.e. it does not matter what the underlying IP address for the hostname is.

Comment: what else could cause the invalid certificate error then?

Comment: @jp1977: That you have the correct certificate configured at the wrong place. Or that you have configured the wrong certificate at the correct place.Or the hostname you use in the URL does not actually match the certificate even if you claim so.  Unfortunately it is unclear what you have actually configured and what you are doing, so it impossible to say where exactly the error is.